# How do I trap arguments to a target method when using a Proxy object?

Tags: javascript, metaprogramming, es6-proxy

I'm trying to use [Javascript `Proxy` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to trap the arguments that are passed to a 'method' of the target that I'm proxying.

Please consider this example:

```
var test = {
    doSomething: function() {
        console.log( arguments.length );
    }
};

var testProxy = new Proxy( test, {
    get: function( target, property, receiver ) {

        // I'd like to have access to any arguments when
        // the property being accessed here is a function
        // that is being called

        return target[ property ];
    }
} );

testProxy.doSomething( 'this', 'is', 'lame' ); // I want to trap those arguments
```

It appears that these `Proxy` objects only allow you to trap accessing the property, but not the actual function call, with its arguments, when the property is in fact a function.

After reflecting a bit on the matter, I "get" (pardon the pun) that the `get` method is just intended for property access, in stead of invocation, but then I would have expected to be able to define something like a `call` method in the `Proxy` as well.

Perhaps it's doable with defining an `apply` method in the `Proxy`, but then I'd probably have to create a `Proxy` object for each individual method of the object I want to proxy; and that's not what I am after.

Unless I'm overlooking an actual alternative possibility here: how is it that this is overlooked in the `Proxy` implementation?! Isn't the whole point of a proxy to be able to intercept method calls and their arguments as well?

Or is this yet another misunderstanding of Javascript, on my part, about Javascript not being a 'classical' OOP language, and that the functionality I'm looking for wouldn't actually make sense in the context of Javascript?

Comment: I just realized that there probably *is* a way to achieve what I want; I'll answer my own question if the test I have in mind succeeds.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There actually *is* a way to do this, of course! I just hadn't thought it through thoroughly enough. I can just return a 'proxy' function and trap the arguments in there:

```
var test = {
    doSomething: function() {
        console.log( arguments.length );
    }
};

var testProxy = new Proxy( test, {
    get: function( target, property, receiver ) {

        switch( property ) {
            case 'doSomething':
              // you just have to return a proxy function
              return function() {
                  // arguments accessible, after all!
                  console.log( 'testProxy::doSomething() arguments.length: ' + arguments.length );

                  // here you can still invoke the original method, of course
                  target[ property ].apply( this, arguments );
              }
            break
        }

        return target[ property ];
    }
} );

testProxy.doSomething( 'this', 'is', 'not', 'so', 'lame', 'after', 'all' );
```

Comment: Is there any way to capture the context of the method call as well? I tried the same but the "this" in "target[ property ].apply( this, arguments )" isn't the correct context if your method references "this" in itself...  EDIT: you can pass a reference to the actual target, in your case "target[ property ].apply( test, arguments )"

Comment: @mayacoda I think the correct is: `target[ property ].apply( target, arguments );`

Comment: Man! You are my savior! Thanks for sharing this. I was literally stuck with this for days.

Comment: Ok, i got it working, but there's a catch,  the `return function()` statement is very important, if i do `return () =>` it won't work. Thanks.

Comment: The problem I see with this solution is that inside the proxy function if we are calling a function that works differently depending on the context (e.g. `console.log()` when we want the file and line of the CALLER, and not the ones INSIDE the function), the context is lost (again, e.g. `console.log()` would tell the file an line of the 'target[property].apply...` line. I have not found any solution to this.

Answer (score 5):

another snippet : )

```js
const obj_hidden = {};

const obj = new Proxy(obj_hidden, {
    get(target, prop) {
        if (typeof target[prop] == 'function') {
          return function (...args) {
            console.dir({ call: [prop, ...args] });
            return target[prop].apply(target, args);
          }
        }
        console.dir({ get: prop });
        return target[prop];
    },
    set(target, prop, value) {
        console.dir({ set: [prop, value] });
        target[prop] = value;
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Makes no sense doing `...args` when the language already is giving it to you via `arguments` when using a "regular" function and not an arrow function. Upvoted as a good answer.

Comment: @vsync problem with `arguments` is 1) its obscure and 2) its an object, not an array

Comment: Doesn't matter for this example. Been using `arguments` for 20 years almost, no problems. if you need to convert it to array simple do `[...arguments]`

Answer (score 1):

Here's another snippet

```js
var test = {
    doSomething: function() {
        console.log( arguments.length );
    }
};

var testProxy = new Proxy( test, {
    get: function( target, property, receiver ) {

          // to have access to any arguments
    
          return ( ...args ) => target[property].apply(target, args);
          
      }
});

const value = testProxy.doSomething( 'this', 'is', 'lame' ); // those arguments will be trapped
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing your answer. It helped me figure out how to fix my problem, which is fairly similar to this one. I figured I share mine as well, maybe it will be helpful.

I intended to wrap the arguments of the callback function passed to promise objects(the resolve and reject function when creating a new promise). So I created a proxy for Promise object to modify the constructor, but in the constructor, I couldn't access the arguments of the first argument of the promise constructor. This is how I did it, thanks to [Decent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25069451/7025986)

```js
// Wrap promise:
let promiseWrapperHandlers = {
  construct: function(target, args) {
    let originalCb = args[0]
    if (typeof args[0] === 'function') {

      let wrappedCb = function() {
        let resFn = arguments[0] || (() => {})
        let wrappedResolve = function(v) {
          console.log("resolving promise with " + v);
          return resFn(v);
        }

        let rejFn = arguments[1] || (() => {})
        let wrappedReject = function(err) {
          console.log("rejecting promise with " + err);
          return rejFn(err);
        }

        return originalCb(wrappedResolve, wrappedReject)
      }
      args[0] = wrappedCb
    }


    let p = new target(...args)
    return p
  },
}

const RealPromise = Promise
Promise = new Proxy(RealPromise, promiseWrapperHandlers)
// END wrap promise

const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(122)
})
const p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  reject(121)
})
```