# Cannot access class method through a proxy object

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

like in the title I can't access class method through a proxy object, I get the error

```
TypeError: sth.getNumber is not a function
```

But before I see that It was accessed like property because I see "get" log in the terminal

I don't really know why this is happening.
Below it's my simplified example of what I want to do.
Thanks in advance for help

```
class mockClass {
  sth?: number
  constructor(n?: number) {
    this.sth = n
  }
  public getNumber(n: number) {
    return n
  }
}

const sth = new Proxy<any>(new mockClass(15), {
  apply: function (target, thisArg, argArr) {
    console.log("apply")
    console.log(target, thisArg, argArr)
    return "a"
  },
  get: function (target, reciver) {
    console.log("get")
    console.log(target, reciver)
    return "b"
  },
})

console.log(sth.getNumber(15))
```

Comment: You're returning the string "b" from the `Proxy`. "b" is indeed not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
get: function (target, reciver) {
    console.log("get")
    console.log(target, reciver)
    return "b"
  },
```

To:

```
get: function (target, reciver) {
    console.log("get")
    console.log(target, reciver)
    return () => { return "b"}
  },
```

Comment: I think my answer is a bit primitive but it works. I saw later this discussion with a nice solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25069023/how-do-i-trap-arguments-to-a-target-method-when-using-a-proxy-object